# Exception error despite try-catch and throws Exception attempts

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I am very confused because I have this code below which I believe should catch exceptions:

```js
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static String method(String userToken, int nthRecent) throws Exception
    {
      //my own user Token: 35a5b026870c49f69d3c688779ff26db
      String tweet = tweets.get(nthRecent);
      try
      {
         String urlString = "https://api.dandelion.eu/datatxt/sent/v1/?lang=en&text=";
         urlString += tweet;
         urlString = urlString + "&token="+userToken; 
         
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         con.setRequestMethod("GET");
         
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
         String line; 
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
         {
            response.append(line);
         }
         in.close();
         return response.toString();
         con.disconnect();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
      }
   }
```

But I keep on getting this error message:

> TwitterPart3.java:42: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>   consolePrint.println(bigBird.method(userToken, nthRecent));

Am I throwing the wrong exception? I've tried both the try-catch and throwing, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Update:
Below is my main method:

```js
   private static PrintStream consolePrint;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException
   {
        consolePrint = System.out;
        SentimentAnalyser bigBird = new SentimentAnalyser(consolePrint);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        consolePrint.print("Please enter a Twitter handle, do not include the @symbol --> ");
        String twitter_handle = scan.next();
        
        while(!twitter_handle.equals("done"))
        {
            bigBird.queryHandle(twitter_handle);
            consolePrint.print("Enter the \"nth\" most recent tweet you would like analysed from " + twitter_handle + "--> ");
            int nthRecent = scan.nextInt();
            consolePrint.print("Enter your user Token " + twitter_handle + "--> ");
            String userToken = scan.next(); 
            consolePrint.println(bigBird.method(userToken, nthRecent)); // this is the line 42 the error refers to
            twitter_handle = scan.next();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Which is the line 42 of `TwitterPart3`  ?

Comment: ah, line 42 is actually the main method

Comment: consolePrint.println(bigBird.method(userToken, nthRecent));

Comment: The error message talks about consolePrint.println, which appears nowhere in the posted code. So the error is not related to the code you posted. Read it carefully: it has a file name and a line number.

Comment: I will actually update the entirety of my main method, if that helps.

Comment: `method` is declared as throwing `Exception` , its callers must  take this into account. Or, just remove `throws Exception` .

Comment: @Arnaud how can I take that into account when calling method? I'm quite new to the idea of exceptions, and it's quite confusing

Comment: Catching an exception in method() won't catch an exception that is thrown in main(). consolePrint.println() throws Exception, so you need to catch it, or add `throws Exception` to your main method to propagate it.

Comment: @singularity : Either catch it from the caller method `main`, or declare the caller method as throwing  `Exception` .

Comment: Or remove `throws Exception` from `method()`, since it probably never throws an exception.